# Create required number of sockets during execution

Tags: python, sockets

User parses number of remote machines as a argument(`python scriptName 3`). During the execution script needs to connect and send data to this machines(in this case to 3 machines) in random order.

My code right now:

```
def createSocket(ip):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((ip, 55555))

def sendData(data):
    s.send(data)

def closeSocket():
    s.close()

createSocket(ip)
sendData(data)
closeSocket()
```

So I'm using one socket and re-connect each time I need to connect to other machine. Because of that script transmits data really slowly.

Can I somehow assign required number of sockets during execution and use them? Or maybe there is a better way of keeping connection to all machines?

Comment: Why don't you keep all the sockets open and then close them all when you finish executing your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a single global socket, instead keep a list of sockets. Don't close your sockets after each use, and then reopen them: just keep them open.

eg.

```
def createSocket(ip): # return the new socket object
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((ip, 55555))
    return s

addresses=[ip, ip2, ip3, ...]
sockets=[createSocket(addr) for addr in addresses]

sock = chooseSocket(sockets) # pick one (somehow)
sock.send(data)              # use the selected socket
```

Comment: actually dictionary with keys being IP or tuple(ip, port) might be better

Comment: possibly: I can't tell with any certainty from the OP, so I kept it simple.

Comment: Thanks, will use dictionaries. Just didn't know that I could store socket objects in lists or dictionaries.

Comment: You can store _any_ objects in lists or dictionaries!